# Help with SPICE parameter (in)dependence and real transistors

Tags: bjt, spice, modelling

I am simulating an IC off a manufactures datasheet schematic using suggested integrated BJT Spice parameter values from a textbook. The simulation works well BUT i need to increase storage time and that requires over a magnitude increase in TR from the original value. Even though the simulation seems to work, how physically realistic is this bjt given that all the other spice parameters remain the same. Would other parameters need to be adjusted besides TR so the bjt model would match something in the real world?

Comment: Would [this](https://class.ece.uw.edu/cadta/hspice/chapter_14.pdf) help?

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: “Microelectronic circuit design” by Jaeger and Blalock

Comment: Are you talking about the last column of [this chart found in the Appendix?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXsuK.png)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Just so you know year of the IC, it is the LM306 from Texas-Instruments/National. Maybe there are better values to use for this. BTW, after posting this comment, I started using the AREA multiplier on certain BJT's of this IC and it helps.

Comment: @Mark Roger that.  I'm not sure those "typical" values are really representative of any sort of real-world IC process.  They're probably an averaged set of numbers that work well for the theoretical circuits and problems posed in the textbook.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a good resource for BiPolar IC process SPICE parameters.  CMOS is more common to find, such as [this](http://cmosedu.com/cmos1/cmosedu_models.txt) or [this](http://cmosedu.com/jbaker/courses/ee420_ecg620/s20/C5_models.txt).

Comment: @Mark Actually, I would try looking up VBIC models for BJTs.  See the [LTspice help page on BJTs](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/Q-device.htm).  They are more modern and are likely used today for bipolar IC design, similar to how BSIM3 models are typically used for CMOS ICs.

Comment: @Ste Yeah tell me about it. I found one text "Designing Analog Chips" by Hans Camenzind in which he gives values for BJT "20-volt" technology. What is this "20-volt technology" classification and i would like to find more. Specifically 1960's, 1970's and 1980's tech.